# Archive page/2 not found

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I am using a FSE theme and i am working on the **All archives** template.

I added the Query loop block and now i am dealing with Pagination.

As you know pagination has it own block, I added it and i correctly see the number of pages.

First of all, for testing purpose i set 2 posts per page:

**Settings > Reading**

[image]

I have 3 posts, so i see the page = 2 but when i click on it i get 404 page not found error.

The url i am trying to see is:  **example.com/category_name/page/2**

Why do i get not found error?

P.S. I am not using custom post_type or something like that, i just need to show the blog articles of the category.

Comment: How are your [permalink settings](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/customize-permalinks/) set up?

Comment: The problem was that i used . in the category base.